# How to see data written during tests with AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests

Tags: spring-test

I have some integration test which use AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests. I want to be able to see the changes made to the database during a transaction, both by looking in the database (e.g. when a break point is set) and from another application.

I'm using Postgres, the DataSourceTransactionManager and straight JDBC. I've tried setting the Isolation level for my tests to uncommitted read:

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
public class MyTestFixture
{
    ...
}
```

But it's not making any difference. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using straight JDBC (i.e., no OR-Mapper)? Are you annotating individual test methods with `@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)`? Regarding being able to "see changes made to the database during a transaction", how do propose to do that? Are you setting breakpoints while debugging it?

Comment: Thanks. Straight JDBC, I'm using the @Transactional attribute at test fixture level and yes, I expect to see the changes by setting a break point.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purposes and empirical inspection of the database state, you'll need to ensure that the **client** is configured with an isolation level of `READ_UNCOMMITTED` (if the test code (or tested application code) has not committed its transaction). Setting the isolation level of the test code to `READ_UNCOMMITTED` will only affect what the test code can *see*; it will not affect what other database clients can see.

However, a more robust approach is to use JDBC to query the state of the database within your tests and then assert the expected state. `JdbcTestUtils` provides static methods that make such testing scenarios easier, and `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` includes several `protected` methods as a convenience -- for example, `countRowsInTable`, `countRowsInTableWhere`, etc. You can see an example of this kind of testing in action in the [PetClinic Example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testing-examples-petclinic) in the *Testing* chapter of the Spring Framework Reference Manual. Beyond that, it is a recommended best practice to use Spring's `JdbcTemplate` to directly query the state of the underlying database within transactional integration tests.

Regards,

Sam (author of the *Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Can you explain how to use the example from the documentation? Because [GitHub project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=countRowsInTable) does not contain usage of countRowsInTable method.

Comment: You can see lots of examples within Spring's own test suite: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=countRowsInTable